# Phoenix Path Helper and Phoenix.Param for date-based URI

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix Application, I'd like to have URIs like `http://localhost:4000/2016/07/24/`, which are generated by a `date` field in a struct. I've created a `Phoenix.Param` impl for my struct:

```
defimpl Phoenix.Param, for: Item do
  def to_param(item) do
  {{year, month, day}, _time} = item.date
  "#{year}/#{month}/#{day}/"
end
```

end

Which works as expected, but unfortunately (but understandably) the path helper is escaping that string, so the URI generated by `item_path(@conn, :show, item)` is `http://localhost:4000/2016%2F07%2F24%2F`.

Is there any way to have to path helper accept the path as-is without escaping it? I'm digging through the `Phoenix.Router.Helpers` module, but nothing is jumping out at me.

Edit: I'll add that my current workaround for this is just to define my route as `/:year/:month/:day` instead of just `/:date`, and handle it in my controller's `show` function appropriately, but I'd really prefer the `/:date` route approach.

Comment: Given how ambiguous date formatting can be, I would appreciate the clarity of `/:year/:month/:day` as a reader of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `&URI.decode/1`

```
@conn
|> item_path(:show, item)
|> URI.decode()
```